# Make Procedure with SCOPE_IDENTITY()

Tags: asp.net, sql-server, webforms

I got this three tables

```
CREATE TABLE
(
FirstTableId Int primary key identity,
Something nvarchar(20)
)

CREATE TABLE SecondTable
(
SecondTableId Int primary key identity,
Something nvarchar(20)
)

CREATE TABLE Relation
(
RelationId int primary key identity,
RelationSomething nvarchar(20),
FirstTableId Int, 
SecondTableId Int,
FOREIGN KEY (FirstTableId) REFERENCES FirstTable(FirstTableId),
FOREIGN KEY (SecondTableId) REFERENCES SecondTable(SecondTableId), 
)
```

I create this procedure to insert data into FirstTable and Relation:

```
CREATE PROC InsertInto (@FirstTableId int)
AS
INSERT INTO FirstTable VALUES ('example')
SELECT @FirstTableId = SCOPE_IDENTITY()
INSERT INTO Relation (RelationSomething, FirstTableId, SecondTableId) VALUES ('example', @FirstTableId, 2)
```

I pass values from dropdownlists for example data, and do not pass anything for @FirstTable, because I expect that it get SCOPE_IDENTITY(), but I got error like this: "Must declare the scalar variable "@FirstTableId"? How can I solve this and make it's work?

Comment: Your example code does not recreate the issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to declare the variable in the body and not the Stored Procedure definition. When you declare it in the definition, that means you will pass the value when you call the Stored Procedure.

```
CREATE PROC InsertInto ()
AS
DECLARE @FirstTableId int;
INSERT INTO FirstTable VALUES ('example')
SET @FirstTableId = SCOPE_IDENTITY()
INSERT INTO Relation (RelationSomething, FirstTableId, SecondTableId)     VALUES ('example', @FirstTableId, 2)
```

Comment: The parameter is declared in the procedure. Your code causes the following error: "The variable name '@FirstTableId' has already been declared. Variable names must be unique within a query batch or stored procedure."

Comment: Right. Remove that and add it my way. In that definition, it is needed to be passed in when you call the stored procedure.

Answer (score 1):

Do you have a typo in your actual code? Because in your question you say the procedure parameter is `@FirstTable` and then later say the error is about `@FirstTableId`, and in the example procedure the name of the parameter is `@FirstTableId`.

---

If you do not need to input or output anything from the parameter, declare and use the variable in the procedure.

If you are trying to use an output parameter, then you would declare the parameter as output:

```
create proc InsertInto (@FirstTableId int output) as
begin;
  set nocount, xact_abort on;

  insert into FirstTable 
  values ('example');

  select @FirstTableId = scope_identity();

  insert into Relation (FirstTableId, SecondTableId) values 
  (@FirstTableId, 2);
end;
go
```

and use it like so:

```
declare @id int;
exec insertinto @id output;

select @id as IdOutput;
```

returns

```
+----------+
| IdOutput |
+----------+
|        1 |
+----------+
```

and the row from the relation table:

```
select * from relation;
```

returns

```
+--------------+---------------+
| firsttableid | secondtableid |
+--------------+---------------+
|            1 |             2 |
+--------------+---------------+
```

rextester **demo**: http://rextester.com/VPS78362